# Google test comparar vetor C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Estou montando um projeto e tentando utilizar o google test para comparar o resultado de algumas funções. O problema é que minhas funções retornam vetores de double e só consigo comparar double ou inteiro no google test.

eu tento fazer um:

```
EXPECT_EQ(resposta, FUNC_lib::litopar(ZZIN,AMASS,MULTPL,frac,dens,checawv));
```

No qual resposta é um vetor de double e a FUNC_lib retorna um vetor de double também. Porém ele automaticamente gera o seguinte erro:

```
a nonstatic member reference must be relative to a specific object.
```

Comment: Não é uma boa ideia comparar a igualdade de números de ponto flutuante, por causa dos arredondamentos/erros acumulados e da incapacidade de representarem valores exatos. Veja [Comparing floating point numbers - Random ASCII](https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Até onde eu sei, GoogleTest não tem uma função/macro única para comparar vetores. Mas na [documentação deles](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/Primer.md) tem um exemplo de como fazer isso:

```
ASSERT_EQ(x.size(), y.size()) << "Vectors x and y are of unequal length";

for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
   EXPECT_EQ(x[i], y[i]) << "Vectors x and y differ at index " << i;
}
```

Acho que você tem que fazer alguma coisa assim.

P.S.: Como no seu caso você está comparando números reais (ponto flutuante), é melhor usar uma das macros `EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ` ou `EXPECT_NEAR`, documentadas [aqui](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md). Por exemplo, o código pode ficar assim

```
ASSERT_EQ(x.size(), y.size()) << "Vectors x and y are of unequal length";

for (int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
   EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ(x[i], y[i]) << "Vectors x and y differ at index " << i;
   // ou então o seguinte (para usar uma tolerância de comparação de 1e-4):
   // EXPECT_NEAR(x[i], y[i], 1.e-4) << "Vectors x and y differ at index " << i;
}
```

Comment: Show, isso vai servir.